# unable to display data in fullcalender

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) and I want to display JSON data in this calendar but I get an error displaying data received in JSON format through AJAX call -- the data is not displaying. How can I display the data in JavaScript?

I have included files:
fullcalendar.css, fullcalendar.print.css, moment.min.js, jquery.min.js,fullcalendar.min.js

Her is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id='calendar'></div> 

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#get_schedule").click(function(){
      var clas=$("#selectclass").val();
      var section=$("#selectsection").val();

      $.ajax({
        url:'events7.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{class_name:clas,class_id:section},
        success:function(resp){
          if(resp!=''){
            alert(resp);
            $("#calendar").fullcalendar({
              eventSources:
              {
                url: 'events7.php', // for lectures
                color: '#FF4D4D',
                textColor: 'black'
              },

            })
          }else{
            alert(1);
          }
        }
      });
    })
  })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are there any errors displayed? Or maybe something in console?

Comment: @naXa  Thanks! Well there is no such error. I can only get data in an alert of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Let `resp` as `Array` returns from server.And let `jobCode` and `totalHours` belongs to each `resp[i]`. Following is the implementation which integrate with qTip to show **jobCode** and **totalHour** of each items in the array. The catch is to set the **events** property of fullCalender with your array.

```
      $('#mycal').fullCalendar({
             events: resp,
             allDay: false,
                  eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    var title = element.find( '.fc-title' );
                    var title = element.find( '.fc-time' ).text('');
                    title.text(event.jobCode);
                      element.qtip({    
                          content: {    
                              title: { text: event.jobCode },
                              text: '<span class="title">Duration: </span>' + event.totalHours+" hours" 
                              + '<br><span class="title">Description: </span>' + event.jobCode          
                          },
                          style: { 
                              width: 200,
                              padding: 5,
                              color: 'black',
                              textAlign: 'left',
                              border: {
                              width: 1,
                              radius: 3
                           },
                              tip: 'topLeft',

                              classes: { 
                                  tooltip: 'ui-widget', 
                                  tip: 'ui-widget', 
                                  title: 'ui-widget-header', 
                                  content: 'ui-widget-content' 
                              } 
                          } 
                      });
                  }
        });
```